# How to display Gujarati Word from Database on php page?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf-16

I have Gujarati word in Database. Collation is `utf8mb4_croatian_ci`

[image]

But when I list those word on page it display `?????`.

[image]

I have use `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` on page header but still it is not working.

Comment: Try out this as meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @contributor Stil comming  `???`

Comment: try this instead : `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and make sure that the table,columns are set to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: currently columns are set to  `utf8mb4_croatian_ci`.  and if I set it to `utf8_general_ci` still `?????` coming. @contributor

Comment: try to get the `name` in your `phpmyadmin` and see what you got there, try to run the same query in your `phpmyadmin` .

Comment: post your `code`, that would be better

Comment: I don't know what `variable` you are using, try this before your `sql` query , and see if it works `$con->set_charset("utf8");`,match your `charset` with yours, I'm using `$con` as the `connection` variable, use yours accordingly.

Comment: I have used `mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");`    It is working for  inserting Gujarati word and it also store Gujarati word in data base but it create problem for displaying data from databse. @contributor

Comment: Thanks Its working  I need to remove `utf8_decode`  from `echo utf8_decode($row['name']);` @contributor

Comment: glad to hear that,  @MeetPatel

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored